# Pagination in jsp without any jquery or js

Tags: jsp, pagination

I need a pagination link like , `Prev 1-10 Next` , `Prev 11-20 Next` etc..
I have an array list say arList and which holds 300 records.I need to show the first 10 records first. While clicking next only, I need to show the next 10.

Can anyone share a link or resources have a similar idea like this?

```
ArrayList arList  = new ArrayList();
arList = // calling method to retrieve elements

// table starts here
<table id="tbl">


 for(int i=0; i < arList.size();i++) 
 {
 HashMap hMap=(HashMap)arList.get(i);                        
 firstVal= (String)hMap.get("first");
 secondVal= (String)hMap.get("second");
%><tr><td> 
// firstVal and secondVal goes here
</tr></td><%
 }

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use JSTL for this!!

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item" begin="0" end="9">
    ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

You can even use EL in those attributes.

```
request.setAttribute("firstrow", 0);
request.setAttribute("rowcount", 10)

<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item" begin="${firstrow}" end="${firstrow + rowcount - 1}">
    ${item}
</c:forEach>
```